# How to Expose Install Directory as a Public Property in Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

My Windows Forms Application should be installed quietly using `msiexec`. I'd like to expose the Install Directory as a Public Property to enable the system administrator to change it using the command line only. Something similar to this would be nice:

```
msiexec /i MySetup.msi /quiet INSTALLDIR="E:\MyTool"
```

Is there a way in Visual Studio to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio setup projects use TARGETDIR property for Application Folder. So you can use a command line which looks lime this:

```
msiexec /i MySetup.msi /quiet TARGETDIR="E:\MyTool"
```